# Modifying an unknown tuple in c++ to add all numeric objects and concatenate all objects that can cast to a string

Tags: c++, tuples, iteration

My goal is given an unknown tuple I want to just print the outputs of a) everything that is numeric added together and b everthing that can be cast to a string to be concatenated. So for example if I was given a random tuple t(1,true,"hello",2.1f,"world") the output would be 3.1, "hello world"

I'm not that proficient in c++ this is the code I have so far

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


template <size_t I = 0, typename... Ts>
typename enable_if<I == sizeof...(Ts), void>::type
printTuple(tuple<Ts...> t)
{
    
    return;
}
 
template <size_t I = 0, typename... Ts>
typename enable_if<(I < sizeof...(Ts)), void>::type

printTuple(tuple<Ts...> t)
{
   
    cout << get<I>(t) << " ";
 
    
    printTuple<I + 1>(t);
}
 

int main()
{
    
    tuple <int32_t, bool, std::string, float, const char*> t(1,"Hello",true,"World",19.1f);
    
    printTuple(t);
    return 0;
}
```

the code iterates through it but I cant add the unknown objects together or concatenate them, I appreciate the help thank you.

Comment: Please specify problem more clearly. Do you want just print contents of tuple? If it is something more complex provide couple examples of input data (tuples) and expected output.

Comment: Please [edit] your question when you are asked for more information. Other users should be able to answer just by reading your question and skipping comments.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::apply` to get all elements of tuple.

Use fold expression `(action,...)` to perform some operartion on each tuple elements.

Use `if constexpr` to check if tuple element is numeric or string convertible value:

```
template<class ... Args>
auto sum(std::tuple<Args...> const& t) {
    double res = 0.0;
    auto addToRes = [&](auto arg){
        if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(arg)>)
            res += arg;
    };
    std::apply([&](auto&&... args){ (addToRes(args),...); }, t);
    return res;
}

template<class ... Args>
auto concat(std::tuple<Args...> const& t) {
    std::string res;
    auto addToRes = [&](auto arg){
        if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<decltype(arg), std::string>)
            res += arg;
    };
    std::apply([&](auto&&... args){ (addToRes(args),...); }, t);
    return res;
}

template<class ... Args>
void foo(std::tuple<Args...> t) {
    std::cout << sum(t) << std::endl; // 41
    std::cout << concat(t) << std::endl; // sstrxxx
}

int main(){
    const char* p = "s";
    foo(std::make_tuple(p,1,10u,10L,10.0f,std::string("str"),10.0,"xxx"));
}
```

Comment: If i wanted to add a counter to track the number of objrcts in the tuple that are not arithmetic or can be concatenated would i use a similar method?  For example trying to get tuple(true,true,true,10,10) to output 20, 3?